# php-mailparse composer not loading on server

Tags: php, composer-php, email-parsing

I have an Ubuntu php7.0 server and I am trying to use a php Mailparse script I found here

However I confirmed that composer is installed on the server and mailparse is also on the server. However the below script returns a 500 error and I tracked it down to the top two lines of code that is causing it and not sure how to resolve it.

So what I mean is when I comment out the two lines that say

```
   require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
   $Parser = new PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();
```

Then the script will load but of course the mail parse wont work??

```
 //load the php mime parse library
   require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

   $Parser = new PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();

//Include the AWS SDK using the Composer autoloader.
require 'awssdk/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
// AWS Info
$bucketName = 'pipedemail';
$IAM_KEY = '******';
$IAM_SECRET = '******';
// Connect to AWS
try {
    // You may need to change the region. It will say in the URL when the bucket is open
    // and on creation. us-east-2 is Ohio, us-east-1 is North Virgina
    $s3 = S3Client::factory(
        array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => $IAM_KEY,
                'secret' => $IAM_SECRET
            ),
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1'
        )
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // We use a die, so if this fails. It stops here. Typically this is a REST call so this would
    // return a json object.
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Use the high-level iterators (returns ALL of your objects).
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => $bucketName));

foreach ($objects as $object) 
{
    $objectkey = $object['Key'];
    $path = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pipedemail/$objectkey";

    //lets get the raw email file to parse it
    $Parser->setText(file_get_contents($path));

    // Once we've indicated where to find the mail, we can parse out the data
    $to = $Parser->getHeader('to');             // "test" <test@example.com>, "test2" <test2@example.com>
    $addressesTo = $Parser->getAddresses('to'); //Return an array : [[test, test@example.com, false],[test2, test2@example.com, false]]

    $from = $Parser->getHeader('from');             // "test" <test@example.com>
    $addressesFrom = $Parser->getAddresses('from'); //Return an array : test, test@example.com, false

    $subject = $Parser->getHeader('subject');

}
```

Comment: Well, in most cases of error 500, there is an error message placed in the server's log file. Search for it and add the error message here

Comment: When I look at the error.log I see
 PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Parser in test.php on line 46
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setText() on null

Comment: Yeah, thats a pretty obvious error message.... have you read and understood it?

Comment: I do not understand what it means which is why I am posting here. I have installed the php-mailparse module and ensured it is enabled on the server. However I believe the error message means the server does not see that the php-mailparse module is on the server and so it is not able to interpret the line 46 ?

Comment: "Call to a member function setText() on null" means that there is a call to a function on a null variable. So, if line 46 is the one doing `$Parser->setText()`, the variable `$Parser" is not defined, as told in the PHP notice. So, the question is: in which state is your code? Does it throw error 500 with the line `$Parser = new PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();` commented out, that exactly is your problem. Otherwise, there might be a problem directly after that line - so use `var_dump` or a proper debugger to see whether `$Parser` is null

Comment: Thank you Nico, as my OP states when I comment out the two rows

  require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
  $Parser = new PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();

Both these rows are causing the 500 error so my question really is
if I have composer installed why is the line 
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
not working?

Comment: So, then don't comment them out: its very obvious that `$Parser` is not defined and executing the code throws a fatal error if you don't define that variable....